# How to get position of an image and move another image to that position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anime.js

How do I get the position of the .img class and then move .img-2 class to the same position as .img?
I know I need to get the top and left position of .img based on the window position and then apply those values to my anime.js function, but I'm not doing it correctly...

In the anime.js function I think the translateX & translateY values need to be the values of .img but I'm maybe wrong?

Codepen is [here](https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/WNoLRpB), I'm trying to make this happen when you click the 'BUTTON' link.

Any help is appreciated

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <a class="button" href="javascript:;">BUTTON</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
           <img class="img-2" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row bottom-row">
    <div>
        <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.bottom-row {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  marign-top: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  
   const eTop = $('.img').offset().top; //get the offset top of the element
   const eLeft = $('.img').offset().left; //get the offset top of the element

  
  
  $('.button').on('click', function () {
    alert(eTop);
    alert(eLeft);

    anime({
      targets: '.img-2',
      translateY: eTop,
      translateX: eLeft,
      scaleX: 1,
      scaleY: 1,
    });
  });
});
```

Snippit:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

   const eTop = $('.img').offset().top; //get the offset top of the element
   const eLeft = $('.img').offset().left; //get the offset top of the element



  $('.button').on('click', function () {
    alert(eTop);
    alert(eLeft);

    anime({
      targets: '.img-2',
      translateY: eTop,
      translateX: eLeft,
      scaleX: 1,
      scaleY: 1,
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.bottom-row {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  marign-top: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js "></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <a class="button" href="javascript:;">BUTTON</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
           <img class="img-2" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row bottom-row">
    <div>
        <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the top and left offsets were saved in variables before the image had fully loaded. To avoid that, move the `eTop` and `eLeft` lines inside the click handler.

Then, you are doing a translation... So you have to subtract the initial position of the "element to be moved" from the "target" one.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.button').on('click', function() {

    // Target position
    const eTop = $('.img').offset().top; //get the offset top of the element
    const eLeft = $('.img').offset().left; //get the offset top of the element

    // Element to be moved position
    const bTop = $('.img-2').offset().top; //get the offset top of the element
    const bLeft = $('.img-2').offset().left; //get the offset top of the element


    //alert(eTop);
    //alert(eLeft);

    anime({
      targets: '.img-2',
      translateY: eTop - bTop,
      translateX: eLeft - bLeft,
      scaleX: 1,
      scaleY: 1,
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.bottom-row {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  marign-top: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js "></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <a class="button" href="javascript:;">BUTTON</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <img class="img-2" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row bottom-row">
    <div>
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```